# Installing packages for ACOLITE atmospheric correction; RuntimeError - HDF4 DLLs

Tags: python, sentinel-2, landsat-8, atmospheric-correction

I would like to use [ACOLITE atmospheric correction](https://github.com/acolite/acolite) with python, however, I cannot install `pyhdf`.

The RuntimeError is following:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot find required HDF4 DLLs -- check LIBRARY_DIRS
```

I was googling, however I didn't find any specific answer for the error.

What should I do?

I am a Windows user.  However, I can use in an emergency the WSL Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of @Mikkel Lydholm Rasmussen, I've found the answer.

The main issue is in installing `pyhdf` with help of `pip`, but it should be successful with:

`the conda install -c conda-forge pyhdf`

Don't worry to install Anaconda beside the solo python installation and use `Anaconda Prompt` for the manipulation. I also recommend installing other packages in the new environment:

`conda create -n my_env pyhdf ipykernel`

Generally, other packages (GDAL) for ACOLITE will be incompatible with Anaconda standard distribution.